# 'gradle' is currently not installed. though gradle is already installed in system

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, gradle

Installed gradle using

```
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

After installation, used command

```
gradle build
```

It gives error

> The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by
>   typing:
>
> sudo apt-get install gradle

Also followed steps given here:http://exponential.io/blog/2015/03/30/install-gradle-on-ubuntu-linux/. But everytime it gives same error and can not move forward.

Please suggest what is wrong is happening

Comment: Can you post the output of your apt-get command?

Comment: It is giving me same error as mentioned in quote.  The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install gradle

Answer (score 4):

This question is now almost a year old but I chanced on it having run into a similar issue so perhaps the following will help.

I encountered the problem after *upgrading* gradle to [a more recent version](https://wtanaka.com/node/8079). The upgrade installed fine and even ran once, but subsequent calls gave me:

> The program 'gradle' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
>   sudo apt install gradle

I tried to reinstall but Ubuntu was having none of it:

```
gradle is already the newest version (3.5-0ubuntu1).
```

So I had a look at where the installer had put it:

```
whereis gradle
gradle: /usr/lib/gradle
```

Aha! This is a directory, not a path to an executable. Listing the contents of this directory gave me:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 18 11:59 ./
drwxr-xr-x 125 root root 20480 Apr 18 12:17 ../
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Apr 18 11:57 3.5/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 Apr 18 11:59 default -> /usr/lib/gradle/3.5/
```

... and within the `3.5` directory we find the sub-directory `bin` and the executable `gradle`.

Conclusion: Ubuntu took a funny turn during the upgrade and deleted what was probably a symbolic link to the executable.

Solution: create a symbolic link to the executable, taking care to ensure that it's on your `PATH`.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gradle/default/bin/gradle /usr/bin/gradle
```

Finally test that it works:

```
gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.5
------------------------------------------------------------
```